# Cannot resolve type problems with eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jakarta-ee

It seems that I got the wires crossed & ask you to point me the right direction.

I have a problem with the Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (version: 2019-06 (4.12.0), build id: 20190614-1200). There is a code part where I get the error message `MysqlDataSource cannot be resolved to a type`. Searching the Web, I found out that this class is included in the [download of `mysql-connector-java` JAR 8.0.14 with all dependencies](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.14/source-code). I added it over the 'Fix project setup…', where I added the JAR file to the libraries of the **Java Build Path**.
[image]
Unfortunately, the error message does not vanish. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

**Edit 1:**
With the hint from another Website, I found out that the hibernate JAR included was the source files JAR. So, I corrected it the `hibernate-entitymanager` JAR, clicked "Clean…" under "Project", but to no avail: the `EntityManager` is still unlocatable. (Well, after several tries, the first error message to resolve is no more with MySQL.)
[image: Try with the <code>hibernate-entitymanager</code> JAR]

Comment: Are you able to open the `MysqlDataSource` type from the Navigate menu, to verify that it is actually in that jar?

Comment: `MysqlDataSource` is inaccessible over 'Navigate' --> 'Open Type'.

Comment: You have added the zip file in the classpath; extract the JAR from it and add the *JAR*.

Comment: Thank you, Nikos! Actually, Eclipse asks for "`*.jar`, `*.zip`" files. It doesn't matter which format you use. If you unpack the ZIP files, you will become a larger list, but the error remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learned from somebody on another Web site, the following lines have to be added to the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```